# dnspython: module not found in pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, pycharm, python-import, dnspython

I'm trying to connect to MongoDB from the pyCharm environment.
I'm using python 3.8 and I installed pymongo, dnspython and dnspython3.

**My settings** for the project are:

[image: Project Preferences]

**My code is:**

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import argparse
import dnspython

if __name__ == "__main__":
    client = MongoClient("mongodb+srv://rajnesh:<myPassword>@cluster0-chffs.mongodb.net/test?authSource=admin&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&readPreference=primary&appname=MongoDB%20Compass&ssl=true")
    print("Hello there!")
```

However, I get the following **Error**:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/Users/rajnesh/pyProgram.py", line 17, in 
>       import dnspython ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dnspython'
>
> Process finished with exit code 1

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the dnspython package, the import name is "dns". More info about this can be found below:

- http://www.dnspython.org/docs/1.16.0/
- http://www.dnspython.org/examples.html